# Had Voldemort used somebody else's blood, would he have been able to kill Harry in the final duel?

Tags: harry-potter, voldemort, avada-kedavra, lily-potter

Was Lily's original protection not enough for Harry to survive Voldemort's Avada Kedavra in the forbidden forest? I know that the reason given is that Lily's protection is alive in Voldemort's blood, tethering Harry to life, but let's say Voldemort took somebody else's blood in his return to power. Would Harry still have survived the killing curse based on Lily's original sacrifice alone?

Answer (score 2):

The original protection only extended until Harry turned seventeen:

> “We can’t wait for the Trace to break, because the moment you turn seventeen you’ll lose all the protection your mother gave you. In short: Pius Thicknesse thinks he’s got you cornered good and proper.”

In point of fact, it actually ended slightly earlier, when they chose to leave the Dursleys’ house for the last time:

> “So this time, when you leave, there’ll be no going back, and the charm will break the moment you get outside its range. We’re choosing to break it early, because the alternative is waiting for You-Know-Who to come and seize you the moment you turn seventeen.

Comment: Please update to indicate who is speaking in your quotes and which book(s) the quotes are from.